# My authentication using passport and oauth2 cannot redirect to my dashboard page

Tags: passport.js

I used passport and callback was fired. I received the google profile and token in my console but cannot redirect. I checked the googleAPI seems correct. Is there any thing I missed out? What might went wrong? Below is the error msg. Thx.

```
TokenError: Bad Request
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (c:\Users\Xxxxxxx\Desktop\psychoapp\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:358:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (c:\Users\Xxxxxxx\Desktop\psychoapp\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:405:16)
    at c:\Users\Xxxxxxx\Desktop\psychoapp\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:175:45
    at c:\Users\Xxxxxxx\Desktop\psychoapp\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:191:18
    at passBackControl (c:\Users\Xxxxxxx\Desktop\psychoapp\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Xxxxxxx\Desktop\psychoapp\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Comment: Can you give us your code?